# Query default Domain Controller OU LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am trying to figure out how to query a domain to find out where the default domain controllers OU via LDAP.  I am consultant and do know that 99.9% of domains I will come across with have their the standard OU=domain controllers,DC=domain,DC=root.  However, I'm trying to account for that .1% of admins that for what ever reason have moved it to like OU=why,OU=canteven,DC=domain,DC=root.  I know that PowerShell can do this with Get-ADDomain but the tool my development team uses is Python.  POSH will print a line like:

DomainControllersContainer         : OU=Domain Controllers,DC=test,DC=lab

But again, the tools my developers are working on uses python so I'm stuck with traditional LDAP.  Does anyone know where this is stored in AD?  I just need the attribute path so I know where to point my Dev team.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be better to utilize DNS for location of Domain Controllers.
You might be able to use some of this information:
https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/How%20Domain%20Controllers%20Are%20Located%20in%20Windows

As far as I know, there is no "default". The concept of "sites" is done from a ip segment condition.

You can also locate a lot of information about [domain controllers via LDAP Queries](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Getting%20information%20on%20Domain%20Controllers).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  We are also doing it by DNS but I think my Devs want to be dynamic as possible.  I was able to find the answer on this link below of the "wellknownobjects" attribute at the domain root object.  Here is the blog I found below:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/11/25/redirecting-well-known-containers-cnusers-cncomputers-etc/